# Python Flask 2.3.2 and Flask-Security 3.0.0 Roles Management

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am playing around with some Flask applications and try to get into Flask-Security. At this point I want to include the roles_required decorator and I am can not get away from this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'before_first_request'. Did you mean: '_got_first_request'?
```

So far anything else works fine including the @login_required decorator.

**run.py**

```
from app import create_app, db
from config import Config
from app.models import User

app = create_app(Config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**models.py**

```
import secrets
from datetime import datetime

from flask import current_app, request
from flask_security import UserMixin, RoleMixin
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

from app import db

# Define association table for many-to-many relationship
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users', db.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'WEB_Users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

# Flask-Login-Manager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

# Flask-App-Factory
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    # Initialize extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    
    # User loader for Flask-Login
    from app.models import User, Role
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    
    # Extend session validity
    @app.before_request
    def extend_session():
        session.permanent = True

    # Register blueprints
    from app.auth.routes import auth_bp
    from app.dashboard.routes import dashboard_bp

    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(dashboard_bp)

    # Setup Flask-Security
    from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)

    return app
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required
from flask_security import current_user, roles_accepted, roles_required

test = Blueprint('test', __name__)

@test.route('/admin')
@login_required
@roles_required('Admin')
def admin():
    print(current_user.roles)
    return "Admin"
```

Could someone help me out with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using:
https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security-Too/#description

This is a supported fork of the original Flask-Security (with many additional features).

Note that when using Flask-Security - you will need some additional DB fields and you should not have your own UserLoader - let Flask-security handle that.